# Not getting local notification

Tags: swift3

I have done this in my AppDelegate

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {(didAllow, error) in
        if didAllow{
            print("Notification access granted")
        }
        else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    })
```

And in my ViewController class i have done this method to call on a button action

```
func sendNotification(inSecond: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (_ Success: Bool) -> ()){
    let notify = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notify.title = "Break Oil"
    notify.subtitle = "Please renew your Break Oil"
    notify.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "carsHrn.mp3")
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: inSecond, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content: notify, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
            completion(false)
        }
        else    {
            completion(true)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`'s delegate method: `func userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`? Otherwise you won't get notification when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: Where should i implement this , in appDelegate or in view controller class ?

Comment: I guess you have some gap in understanding _how delegates work in iOS_. You should study delegation pattern (e.g. how to adopt/conform to protocols, how to handle delegate methods etc.) in details. It's not a good question asking _"where should I write this"_. By the way, for the time being have a look at this [Local Notifications With the User Notifications Framework](https://cocoacasts.com/local-notifications-with-the-user-notifications-framework/) tutorial for your need.

Comment: i have implemented ...    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        print("Tapped in notification")
    }
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Notification being triggered")            
         completionHandler( [.alert,.sound,.badge])
    }
}

Comment: Still it's not working that's why i ask you ..

Comment: I have added custom sound for notification , after given timeInterval i got notification sound but not notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using 
extension DignoSViewController : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert])
}
```

}